# Difference between AuthenticateAsClient and AuthenticateAsServer

Tags: c#, sslstream

What is the difference between `SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient` and `SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer` methods?
When should I use what?
 
I checked many examples. But I can't understand what should be used by client and what should be used by server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AuthenticateAsServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasserver(v=vs.110).aspx) is called from the server process.  Both overloads to this method (and its Async sibling) take an X509Certificate object, which is the server authentication certificate.

[AuthenticateAsClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is called from the client process.  Both overloads to this method (and its Async sibling) take a string, which is the hostname to use for policy matching on the server's authentication certificate.

Comment: Still this is too complex for me to understand. Sorry.

Comment: @LasithaYapa Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, then. Maybe it would help if you clarify in the question 1) what you want to do, 2) what parts you understand, and 3) what parts you don't.

Comment: Actually this is what i wanted. I'm going to accept it. What i'm saying is that it's better if you can add more details to simplify understanding.